# PHP on IIS - Exec Returns 1

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2008, exec

I have ImageMagick, IIS 6, Ghostscript, and PHP 5.3.1 installed on a Windows Server 2008 box and am trying to convert a PDF file into a JPG thumbnail.

However, it doesn't seem to be working-- the call to `exec()` produces a return code of 1 (which to my understanding, means that some general error has occurred). The output variable is simply an empty array. `$output` is simply an empty array. The same occurs if I use `system()` instead of `exec()`

Running the command from the command line seems to work, so my initial guess would be a simple permission issue... The directory is writable by PHP because the script that uploads a PDF to the directory works, and I have verified that everyone has permission to write to the directory as well.

Also, safe mode is off.

Any ideas as to what the issue could be?

Relevant code:

```
<?php
    $output = array();
    $ret = 0;
    echo exec('convert D:\content\myfile.pdf[0] D:\content\myfile_thumb_1.jpg', $output, $ret);
    var_dump($ret);
?>
```

*Note: While I would test this on Apache on Mac OS X, I can't seem to get ImageMagick or Ghostscript installed correctly.*

I've also ensured the following:

- Correct case for the file names (all lowercase anyways)
- Using the full path of convert.exe in addition to simply convert.exe

UPDATE:

After checking the task manager, convert.exe is being run and is taking up CPU time, suggesting to me that it is file permissions of some sort... I'm going to check it out now.

Comment: $output is an empty array after the exec call. Also, nothing is echoed-- the return code I am referring to is the `var_dump` of `$ret`, which is an integer (1)

Comment: I don't actually need to output anything-- it's just there for debugging right now. I'm not actually expecting any output except for the JPG, really. `exec('DIR')` works perfectly and as expected and displays the contents of the directory the script is in.

Comment: Silly question maybe, but what happens if you specify the full path to `convert(.exe?)` ?

Comment: Kev is right, try to add .exe to the command, and preferably the path to the convert.exe file too. You do not need the echo before exec, so just use it like this: exec('c:/imagemagick/convert.exe D:\content\myfile.pdf[0] D:\content\myfile_thumb_1.jpg', $output, $ret);
You can also try double backslash (\\) instead of single slash (/) in the path if that may disturb IIS. Also take care of the upper lower cases in the path and file names, windows works weird in them.
If I were you, I would put apache on the windows machine instead of IIS, it works fine even on windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, supplying the full path to ImageMagick's convert.exe does not work and still returns 1. As with before, the command works from the command prompt. Double backslashes also aren't working, and  everything is the correct case (lower case). Would it make a difference if the file was on the `D:/` drive versus the `C:/` drive where all the programs are installed? The actual sites are stored under a separate drive then Windows/IIS/ImageMagick. While I would normally use Apache (I usually use Linux + Apache for my own stuff), unfortunately I won't be able to for this application.

Comment: Interestingly, when running the PHP script through the command line (ie. php convert.php), the file conversion works. That tells me it is a permission issue and the IIS user doesn't have permission to execute or write something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was a permission issue with something in IIS-- the website ran under a different user than the command from CMD, which obviously results in it not working under IIS because it has lesser permissions than from CMD.

Comment: how did you solve the problem then? how can i set the correct permissions?

Comment: whats the solution, please specify